# Debugging/Decoding DNA Java

Tags: java, dna-sequence

I'm trying to debug my program for errors; for example the error `incompatible types: edu.duke.StorageResource cannot be converted to java.lang.String` on the line `String geneList = FMG.storeAll(dna);` what does it mean?.

The storeAll and printGenes methods is what I'm having trouble with. I can't seem to get the syntax right for storing genes. I have a basic outline of what it should look like but I don't know how to use the StorageResource properly. Also in the printGenes method, I don't know what is needed so all of my desired print statements execute. Specifically I'd like to know (what the syntax is of) how to count up the number of genes, count the characters in the DNA strand, etc.. Also I have a problem with the location of where I should call the methods that I have already created; I want to know the exact location, in the code. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

(PS: The main method has been changed to `printGenes` method, because my class uses BlueJ in which you can't call Main methods.

Here is where you can download the file necessary to do this assignment, http://www.dukelearntoprogram.com/course2/data/dna.zip
Any suggestions are helpful.

Here's my faulty code:

```
import java.io.*;
import edu.duke.FileResource;
import edu.duke.StorageResource;
import edu.duke.DirectoryResource;

public class FindMultiGenes5 {
    public int findStopIndex(String dna, int index) {
        int stop1 = dna.indexOf("TGA", index);
        if (stop1 == -1 || (stop1 - index) % 3 != 0) {
            stop1 = dna.length();
        }
        int stop2 = dna.indexOf("TAA", index);
        if (stop2 == -1 || (stop2 - index) % 3 != 0) {
            stop2 = dna.length();
        }
        int stop3 = dna.indexOf("TAG", index);
        if (stop3 == -1 || (stop3 - index) % 3 != 0) {
            stop3 = dna.length();
        }
        return Math.min(stop1, Math.min(stop2, stop3));
    }

    public StorageResource storeAll(String dna) {

        //CATGTAATAGATGAATGACTGATAGATATGCTTGTATGCTATGAAAATGTGAAATGACCCAdna = "CATGTAATAGATGAATGACTGATAGATATGCTTGTATGCTATGAAAATGTGAAATGACCCA";

        String sequence = dna.toUpperCase();
        StorageResource store = new StorageResource();
        int index = 0;


        while (true) {
            index = sequence.indexOf("ATG", index);
            if (index == -1)
                break;

            int stop = findStopIndex(sequence, index + 3);

            if (stop != sequence.length()) {
                String gene = dna.substring(index, stop + 3);
                store.add(gene);

                System.out.println("From: " + index + " to " + stop + " Gene: " + gene );//index = sequence.substring(index, stop + 3).length();
            index = stop + 3; // start at the end of the stop codon
          }else{  index = index + 3;
        }

    }
    return store;//System.out.println(sequence);
    }
   public void testStorageFinder() {
      DirectoryResource dr = new DirectoryResource();
      StorageResource dnaStore = new StorageResource(); 
    for (File f : dr.selectedFiles()) {
        FileResource fr = new FileResource(f);
        String s = fr.asString();
        dnaStore = storeAll(s);
        printGenes(dnaStore);
    }


        System.out.println("size = " + dnaStore.size());

    }  
  public String readStrFromFile(){

        FileResource readFile = new FileResource();

        String DNA = readFile.asString();

        //System.out.println("DNA: " + DNA);

        return DNA;

    }//end readStrFromFile() method;
  public float calCGRatio(String gene){

        gene = gene.toUpperCase();  
        int len = gene.length();
        int CGCount = 0;

        for(int i=0; i<len; i++){

            if(gene.charAt(i) == 'C' || gene.charAt(i) == 'G')
                CGCount++;

        }//end for loop

        System.out.println("CGCount " + CGCount + " Length: " + len + " Ratio: " + (float)CGCount/len);
        return (float)CGCount/len;
    }//end of calCGRatio() method;
    public void printGenes(StorageResource sr){
   for(String gene: sr.data()){
     if (gene.length() > 60) {
       System.out.println(gene.length()+"\t"+gene);
     }
     if(calCGRatio(gene)> 0.35) {
       System.out.println(gene.length()+"\t"+gene);
      }
  }

        //create a FindMultiGenesFile object FMG
        FindMultiGenes5 FMG = new FindMultiGenes5();

        //read a DNA sequence from file
        String dna = FMG.readStrFromFile();

        String geneList = FMG.storeAll(dna);

        //store all genes into a document
        StorageResource dnaStore = new StorageResource();

        System.out.println("\n There are " + geneList.size() + " genes. ");

        int longerthan60 = 0;
        int CGGreaterthan35 = 0;
        for(int i=0; i<geneList.size(); i++){

            if(!dnaStore.contains(geneList.get(i)))
                dnaStore.add(geneList.get(i));

            if(geneList.get(i).length() > 60) longerthan60++;
            if(FMG.calCGRatio(geneList.get(i)) > 0.35) CGGreaterthan35++;

        }

        System.out.println("dnaStore.size: " + dnaStore.size());


        System.out.println("\n There are " + dnaStore.size() + " genes. ");
        System.out.println("There are " + longerthan60 + " genes longer than 60.");
        System.out.println("There are " + CGGreaterthan35 + " genes with CG ratio greater than 0.35.");
    }//end main();
}
```

Comment: Do you want *help* as in you're stuck with something, or do you want us to actually *do* this work?  You'll only ever get the former, and only after you tell us what's specifically broken and where you're stuck.

Comment: I've edited the question to reflect what the real problems are that I'm having.

Answer (score 0):

Your `storeAll` method is defined as

```
public StorageResource storeAll(String dna)
```

This means the storeAll method returns object of type `StorageResource`. But you have used

```
String geneList = FMG.storeAll(dna);
```

The type of variable used in left side is `string` but the type of variable that right side returns is `StorageResource`. This cannot be done, because **Java** does not know how to convert `StorageResource` to `String`. As far as your problem is concerned, writing these many lines are not necessary. To print genes stored in `StorageResource`, you can write:

```
public void printAll(StorageResource s){
    for(String gene : s.data())
        System.out.println(gene);
}
```

To count genes of length greater than 60 or cg ratio greater than .35, or find longest gene on one go, you can modify above program and do following

```
public void printAll(StorageResource s){
    int count60 = 0;
    int cg35 = 0;
    int longest = null;

    for (String gene : s.data()){
        System.out.println(gene.length() + "\t" + gene);
        if (gene.length() > 60) count60++;
        if (cgRatio(gene) > 0.35) cg35++;
        if (gene.length() > longest) longest = gene.length();
    }

    System.out.println("Greater than 60 nucleotides is "+ count60);
    System.out.println("Longest gene length is "+ longest);
    System.out.println("CG ratio greater than 0.35 is "+ countCG);
}
```

For finding CG ratio, you can do following

```
public float cgRatio(String gene){
    int c = gene.length() - gene.replace("c", "").length();
    int g = gene.length() - gene.replace("g", "").length();

    return ((float) c + g) / gene.length();
}
```